# Unable to delete entity which has owned entity in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

And using fluent API I have configured the owned entity as following:

```
 private void ConfigureEmployee(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
{
    builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Address, w =>
    {
        w.Property(x => x.City).HasMaxLength(100);
        w.Property(x => x.State).HasMaxLength(100);
    });
}
```

And when I try to delete Employee entity :

```
var employee = dbContext.Employees.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
dbContext.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Deleted;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I got the following exception:

> The entity of type 'Employee' is sharing the table 'Employees' with entities of type 'Employee.Address#Address', but there is no entity of this type with the same key value '{Id: 1ad382d7-4064-49a3-87ee-633578175247}' that has been marked as 'Deleted'.

I have tried the workaround specified [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12118#issuecomment-392898117) but it didn't work.

I am using EntityFrameworkCore v2.2.4

Comment: You can specify the `delete` behavior on the navigation to let `delete on cascade`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to the way you load the entity. When you do:

```
var employee = dbContext.Employees.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
```

You're basically saying to EF: Load this `Employee` for me but forget about it. Treat it as if you never had loaded it in the first place.

Next, you want to delete it. You know that it's not being tracked by `DbContext` so you do:

```
dbContext.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

This is the "key" to the issue. This line tells the `DbContext`: Hey, Please start tracking this entity and mark it as to be deleted.

**The issue:** The `Employee` entity **owns** an address but the `DbContext` **is not aware** that you also want to delete it.

The error message you get offers a lot of insight on the actual error, but it might not be that clear at first sight:

> The entity of type 'Employee' is sharing the table 'Employees' with entities of type 'Employee.Address#Address', but there is no entity of this type with the same key value '{Id: 1ad382d7-4064-49a3-87ee-633578175247}' that has been marked as 'Deleted'.

This is saying: The entity `Employee` with id 4 is marked as `Deleted` but it also has an **entity** of type `Address` which **was not added to be deleted**. Although you don't have `Address` declared as a `DbSet` in your context, it is still an actual Entity as far as EF is concerned.

To fix it while keeping the same code as you have you need to also add the `Address` to be deleted:

```
context.Entry(employee.Address).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

**But:**

I'm not sure if this is just a sample or if it's your real code. But, I personally (and I see many also against it) try to avoid as much as possible manipulating the entity states manually. This can get nasty pretty quickly and produce, as you already experienced it not so obvious results. Instead, if you have a `DbContext` which you load the entity you want to delete, you can avoid messing with states and problems by just changing your code to this:

```
var employee = dbContext.Employees.First();

// .Remove will also mark the related entities to be deleted
// If Employee is not tracked, it will also start tracking it
// So, it's not necessary to do .Attach()
dbContext.Remove(employee);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This will work and the entity will be deleted as expected. Of course, if your code is not that and you are, in fact working with entities in a disconnected scenario, then you need to manually set it to be deleted as I showed above.

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments by @IvanStoev, the `Remove` method is what actually can fix the behavior you are facing. The `Remove` method will mark the entity itself plus the related ones as `Deleted` and if not previously tracked, will also start tracking them. From the docs: (emphasis from me)

> If the entity is already tracked in the Added state then the context will stop tracking the entity (rather than marking it as Deleted) since the entity was previously added to the context and does not exist in the database.
>
> Any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked will be tracked in the same way that they would be if Attach(Object) was called before calling this method. **This allows any cascading actions to be applied** when SaveChanges() is called.

[DbContext.Remove Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.remove?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: In my real situation, I have a big graph so I have to fetch it as no tracking so I can traverse it and compare it with a new graph to update the whole graph with its navigation propeties but I have shortcut the question to be easy to understand

Comment: Well.. that in alone is probably a subject to another question, but if you want, adding the `OwnedEntity` manually to be deleted should enable you to delete it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other thing preventing it from being deleted? I just created a sample app and I'm 100% sure it works. I can even push it to GitHub if you want to try it out. If it doesn't then it's something else.

Comment: But, if you look at the error message, it's pretty clear. You share the `Employee` table with the `Address` entity, but you are telling the `DbContext` that you only want to delete the `Employee` part of it. So it is left without knowing what to do with the "rest" of the table, the `Address` part.

Comment: @SimpleCode there you go: https://github.com/joaopgrassi/efcore-ownedentity-delete. Follow the instructions there on how to run it.

Comment: `Remove` is the solution, because it cascades `Deleted` state to related entities, while setting entity entry state doesn't. And owned entity is still entity, not just object.

Comment: @IvanStoev ah this I didn’t know, thanks for letting us know! I love discovering this little hints. And yes.. It is not natural I guess because as you develop you don’t think the owned entity IS an entity.. but for EF it is.

Comment: I edited the answer to consider the comments from @IvanStoev.

Comment: @jpgrassi You are welcome. My comment was mainly for OP, your answer was correct from the beginning - actually both shown approaches work, just `Remove` is more natural.

Comment: @jpgrassi Thanks it worked for me. I didn't know that about Remove

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cascade delete like below:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasOptional<Standard>(s => s.Address)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: I am using OwnsOne and it's a value object in my design